# Is it possible to use language mappings in search-and-replace?

Tags: search-replace

Is is possible to use language mappings (such as those generated by the `'keymap'` option or `:lmap` commands) in `:substitute` search-and-replace commands, the same way they get used in regular searches? If there is no builtin way are there any plugins that do this?

Language mappings in search:
When you have langmaps active they are applied in "search mode", i.e. when you press `/`. This does not happen in the usual command mode.

Comment: In particular it is unclear to me how `langmap` are used in search. I believe `langmap` only impact normal mode and not command mode.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt You're talking about langmap option. But the question is about lmap command.

Comment: Thanks @Matt, You are most probably right but the question should probably edited accordingly ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When switching to the command line mode (i.e. colon but not slash) the `&imsearch` option is forcefully reset "as you're expected to type command" as the help page says.

So you have to switch `&keymap` manually as needed using the same ctrl+6 as always. I see no sense in fighting against this behaviour using tricky autocommands. After all, most of the commands are indeed typed in Latin alphabet only.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to trigger this automatically when I'm doing search-and-replace (e.g. at the same time as `incsearch` goes into effect?)

Comment: @0x539 As I said, you can play with autocommands, but it's not simply worth.